# how to force a subview to load in landscape

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have read other threads but none of them come up with the answer that I want.

How to I make a subview load in landscape?

I have tried

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

but for some weird reason the first time it runs it returns landscape even though the ipad is in portrait?

and Ive looked into the different ways you could do it on prepareForSegue with no luck

Any help greatly apprreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```